# TMRpcm interferes with Wire.h

Tags: tmrpcm

I'm using TMRpcm library for playing .wav files from my SD card. Everything works fine, but if I include Wire.h library the files aren't playing at all (there's no sound). I have only added this line of code above my program:

```
#include <Wire.h>
//code after
```

I suppose that this is because of the timer and interruption because TMRpcm documentation mentions that:

> May interfere with other libraries that rely on interrupts. The isPlaying() disable() or noInterrupts()
>    functions can be used to prevent parallel code execution.

I've tried to use those functions but maybe I do something wrong. Can somebody help me? How can I use those libraries at once?

UPDATE:
Here's my before code:

```
tmrpcm.play("neMode.wav");
delay(2000);
```

and after:

```
noInterrupts();
tmrpcm.play("neMode.wav");
delay(2000);
interrupts();
```

It doesn't change anything. I hear no sound at all.

Comment: How did you use `disable()` and `noInterrupts()`? Please show the code for a complete minimal example, that shows your problem.

Comment: @chrisl I updated my post with that information. Concerning disable() function I don't really know how to use it. I would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: It will not play something, when turning off interrupts. Please show a complete (!) example, that shows your problem.

Comment: Also posted at [Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=607200.0). If you are doing this, you have to link to it, so that we don't spend time on searching for information, that you only gave on one site.

Comment: I cannot see an obvious reason, why it stops working, when including Wire.h. Have you tested, if the Arduino is stuck in some function? You can add simple LED blinks or Serial prints to slowly hunt the problematic code down.

Comment: Well, it stops working exactly after I add a line:
#include <Wire.h>
I'm a beginner in Arduino, that's why I may have some dummy questions. But I can't find a solution of how can I use isPlaying() disable() or noInterrupts() to prevent TMRcpm library from being interrupted. Could you show me please how is it used correctly?

Comment: Besides, the problem may be in timer that these libraries use. I have tried to change TMRpcm library to work with Timer2 in Config.h. But then I just hear noise&beep instead of my file that should be played.